# How many elements of a quaternion you need to uniquely define a rotation

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have a basic (maybe stupid) question which I would like to be 100% sure about.

I already searched online but could not find a precise answer about it.

**How many elements of a quaternion do you need to uniquely define a rotation?**

My answer would be 3 since the fourth can be found knowing that the quaternion must be a unit norm vector.
For sure 2 elements are not enough.

Of course, even with 3 or 4 elements of a quaternion you would have the quaternion ambiguity. I.e. a certain rotation can be expressed by the quaternion $ (q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4) $ or by $ (-q_1, -q_2, -q_3, -q_4) $

Please tell me if I am forgetting anything.

Comment: Totally correct. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

Comment: You can define "a rotation" specifying 1, 2, 3 or 4 components of a quaternion. The number of components dependes on what rotation you want i.e., the axis/angle. For example, identity rotation requires 1 component. Rotation around x-axis requieres only 2 components.  Rotation around an arbitrary axos requires 4 components. I am missing the case of 3 components but you can find it.